# Creating start of GDML file from string

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to use this code

```
s = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gdml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app/releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd">"""

       doctype = """<!DOCTYPE doc [
       <!ENTITY ent SYSTEM "another_doc.xml">
       ]>""" 

       gdml = ET.fromstring(s.encode("UTF-8"))
```

But get XMLSyntaxError: EndTag

I want eventually to add the doctype as well

Answer (score 0):

The string you pass to `fromstring()` needs to be well-formed XML. Since you only have a start tag, it's not well-formed.

This is easily resolvable by self-closing it or adding an end tag.

Also, if you want the XML declaration (`<?xml ...?>`) included in your serialized XML, you can add it to `doctype`.

Example...

```py
from lxml import etree

s = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gdml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app/releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd"/>"""

doctype = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE gdml [
<!ENTITY ent SYSTEM "another_doc.xml">
]>"""

gdml = etree.fromstring(s.encode("UTF-8"))
print(etree.tostring(gdml, doctype=doctype).decode())
```

This prints...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE gdml [
<!ENTITY ent SYSTEM "another_doc.xml">
]>
<gdml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://service-spi.web.cern.ch/service-spi/app/releases/GDML/schema/gdml.xsd"/>
```